# Easy way to log GUI related data with date/time?

Tags: c#

I'm not expert in the field but have a small GUI application in WinForms and similar in WPF C#. I want to use code to be able to log user's actions such as when the user clicked the button, when he executed the program and when the program exited ect.

I need an easy but stable way to log such information to a txt file.

When I started reading about event logging its like a deep ocean and zillions of ways that I dont have such time to grasp all these. I was wondering whether there's a quick simple way for such purpose.

Comment: There are literally 10s of log packages you could use.  If your project is .net core, then the logging framework is built in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a quick and simple way you could have a function like so:

```
static void log(string message)
{
    System.IO.File.AppendAllText(logPath, message + "\r\n");
}
```

You can then set the `logPath` to the `%temp%` folder or whatever when starting the app.

If you want to improve it a bit more, you can add the following:

```
enum LogLevel { Debug, Information, Warning, Error, Critical };

private static void log(string message, LogLevel level = LogLevel.Information)
{
    System.IO.File.AppendAllText(logPath, $"{DateTime.Now:dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss.fff} - {level} - {message}\r\n");
}
```

This makes the log easier to read afterwards.

**Note:** this is a very simple way, if you do not want to dig into using logging frameworks. But Frameworks often give you much more added value, like logging to a database etc.

**Usage:**

```
private void btCreate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    log("Button btCreate clicked.", LogLevel.Warning);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Can you also add an example with an event? Like button clicked is logged with date and error if there is . Your enum LogLevel looks great but can you add an example also how it is used?

Comment: I added a usage. Note, based on where you use it, you might have to remove the term `static` from the `log()` function.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This would work for me. Do you recommend to save this to a txt file or csv? I will send my program to a client and I want it to log whenever people use it.

Comment: `.txt` or `.log`